# Why does gatsby-source-strapi gives 403 error?

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I have a gatsby app. In order to intergrate strapi I installed latest version of gatsby-source-strapi which is ^2.0.0. Strapi app is very simple nothing changed from defaults except that I created a collection and in roles enable find and findOne requests.[image] display name is exactly "ekam"

configuration shown above is added to gatsby-config.js.
Every time I run "gatsby develop" it gives me:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create an access token in Strapi, make sure to give it "Full access" when you choose the "Token type"

Comment: This fixed my problem. Dunno why Gatsby need full access, but read-only is not enough

Answer (score 0):

403 error is a forbidden error. This means that you don't have access to the resource you are requesting.

In your configuration you are not providing the access token hence you don't have access to your CMS. Change the configuration to:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
  options: {
    apiURL: 'http://localhost:1337' // process.env.STRAPI_API_URL,
    accessToken: '123456789' // process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
    collectionTypes: ['ekam'],
  },
},
```

Check the `accessToken` in your Strapi dashboard configuration.

Consider using [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/) for safety instead of adding the tokens directly into the code.

Comment: What do you mean by access token? I mean I created a token in Settings > API Tokens. Then I assigned this token as accessToken field to config. Still didn't work

Comment: You haven't shared the `accessToken` nor the "field to config". Please add the relevant details